# how to read from a binary file and search for a record

Tags: c++, file-io

I am trying to read from a file and search a particular record based on the employee number entered. I have written the code but every time i search for a record which is already present i am getting the message record not found. Can anyone please point out the error.
My code is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

class emp
{
    int empno;
    char name[20];
    char dept[10];
    float salary;
public:
    void getdata()
    {
        cout << "Enter the employee number " << endl;
        cin >> empno;

        cout << "Enter the name : " << endl;
        cin >> name;

        cout << "Enter the department of the employee : " << endl;
        cin >> dept;

        cout << "Enter the salary of the employee : " <<endl;
        cin >> salary;
    }

    void display()
    {
        cout << "Emp No : " <<empno;
        cout << endl << "Name : " << name << endl << "Department : " <<dept <<endl
             <<"Salary : " << salary <<endl;
    }

    int getempno()
    {
        return empno;
    }
};

int main()
{
    emp obj1;
    int eno;
    char ch = 'n';

    ifstream file1("emp.txt", ios:: in); // this file should already exist

    cout << "Enter the employee number to be searched for : " <<endl;
    cin >> eno;

    while(!file1.eof())
    {
        file1.read((char *)&obj1, sizeof(obj1));

        if(obj1.getempno()==eno)
        {
            obj1.display();
            ch = 'y';
            break;
        }
    }

    if(ch =='n')
        cout << "Record Not Found !!" << endl;
    file1.close();
}
```

I am using a variable eno in my main function and comparing the eno to the empno returned from the function getempno. If it is equal i am calling the member function display but the display function is not working. I am only getting the message record not found.

Comment: Problem is with the way you are reading the file. try and print out the contents of the file for clarity..

Comment: I think the problem could be in "eno"... it is being stored as Char*, but compared with an int...

Comment: @user3095272 It's your task to research for the simple solutions 1st, before asking here. It's not the intend of SO to interpret compiler error messages, or debugging your code for you in 1st place :P ...

Comment: @mlwn but the syntax of read function is like this only

Comment: Is it a homework? In real life, using [Sqlite](http://sqlite.org/), [Gdbm](http://www.gnu.org.ua/software/gdbm/) and/or [Json](http://json.org/) should be more practical!

Comment: You should have compiled with all warnings and debug info (`g++ -Wall -g`) then **use a debugger** (e.g. `gdb`), and you'll have found the bug by yourself.

Comment: if you read the file as text, you will not get types back... you need to open it as binary... did you check Christophe answer below ?? if it solves the problem just mark it as Solved..  :)

Comment: @mlwn No opening just in binary mode doesn't help. Using the `operator>>()` will still do text formatting.

Comment: i need to show this in practical class. Trying hard... i m a student of class xii...., a beginner to C++........trying to learn

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, I had the feeling that variable "eno" was read from the file as a string (example "1321" instead of the integer 1321).. I have not much experience in C++, so I cannot be sure 100%

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ i just need the help. i am trying a lot. i am a new learner and cant u experience ppl help me to solve this simple issue.

Comment: @user3095272, can u please upload the file "emp.txt" to somewhere (pastebin for example) for someone to debug your problem here :)

Comment: I am pasting the contents of the emp.txt here. it has just a single record.

Comment: 1000 is the empno, rahul is the name cse is the deoartment and 1299 for salary

Comment: Exactly.. :) file emp.txt is not saved as binary anyway.. it's a normal text file....   // no even data delimiters.... //

Comment: @mlwn then how to save please tell

Comment: Do you have to store your records as binary blobs? It is not portable. If not I recommend writing out the individual fields using text I/O functions << and reading them back in that way too >>. Also can you use `std::string`s?

Comment: the Supposed id which is 1000, is being read as 808464433 lol... just add cout << obj1.getempno(); before the if, and it will display what it reads... the problem is that your data file (emp.txt) is not saved as binary... your program will not know where to split the structure data...

Comment: @user3095272 , what you can do, add another function that writes the record {1000, "Rahul", "cse", 1299} in the file emp.dat (which you will save it as binary), then try to run your program, and use Christophe answer below... I am pretty much sure it will solve your problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the stream as binary as said in the title:

```
   ifstream file1("emp.txt", ios:: in | ios::binary); // binary
```

and also change your loop in order to not test on eof() without having read first:

```
while (file1.read((char *)&obj1, sizeof(obj1)))
```

I could test successfully this updated code, by producing a quick and dirty binary file, written with ios::binary set  (I don't put the constructor code here):

```
void produceTest(string file) {
    ofstream os(file, ios::out | ios::binary);
    emp a(1, "Durand", "IT", 1234.30); 
    emp b(2, "Dupond", "Finance", 1530.20); 
    emp c(25, "Chris", "MD", 15.30); 
    os.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&a), sizeof(emp)); 
    os.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&b), sizeof(emp));
    os.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&c), sizeof(emp));
}
```

If it doesn't work, the problem is with your file.  Potential issues could for example be:

- the file was written without ios::binary, producting alteration of the structure (ignoring 0, on windows tranforming binary bytes 0x0A  into binary 0x0D + binary 0x0A)
- the file was written on a system with a different int encoding (big endian vs.little endian
- the file was written with a leading unicode BOM
- the encoding of the file is not as you thought.